# WordPress Bootstrap carousel

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using 320press.com Wordpress Bootstrap.
Never worked with wordpress before. I found how to add media to featured images and etc, but still can't configure wordpress so it displays carousel.

Can somebody explain briefly in 123 steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On normal Wordpress you'll need to install a plugin in for that. Maybe you can use this tutorial for configuring it: [How to make Bootstrap Carousel display WordPress Dynamic Content](http://www.lanexa.net/2012/04/how-to-make-bootstrap-carousel-display-wordpress-dynamic-content/)

[Wordpress Carousel plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=carousel)

Comment: which one would you recommend for bootstrap?

Comment: I've updated my answer, seems like bootstrap already has a built in carousel plugin which you can use