# How to integrate bootstrap image Carousel with WordPress website

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

i'm a bit of a beginner but i'm in need of a little bit of guidance or push in the right direction. I constructed a bootstrap image carousel using the W3schools tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp). I can implement this into my website that I built from scratch but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it into my WordPress website on the home page. I wanted to build it on my own and implement it into my WordPress website without using any pre-written plugins but can't seem to figure out where I need to be placing my code. Any advice/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress Bootstrap carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642344/wordpress-bootstrap-carousel)

Comment: looks like the link provided is broken

Comment: You can check the plugin parts. If you don't like plugins you can check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344696/integrating-bootstrap-carousel-in-wordpress-without-plugin

Comment: definitely closer to what I'm looking for. I think my issue is where to be placing my actual code if I want it to be the header of my home page sliding between 3 different posts.

Comment: You can edit the template and add your code there.

Comment: I have a layout called header, would it make sense to put my code into a custom html widget within the header layout?

Comment: More resource for you: https://www.wpexplorer.com/add-custom-code-wordpress/